# document.getElementsByClassName.length is = 0

Tags: javascript

I have no clue as to why `console.log(li.length);` returns `0` when `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item"));` returns an array. `console.log("AFTER");` gets printed after the array, so it looks like it completed skips the 2nd for loop but I define the li elements beforehand.

```js
var categories = ["business", "entertainment", "gaming", "general", "music", "science-and-nature", "sport", "technology"];
  function makeUL(array) {

    var overview = document.createElement('div');
    overview.setAttribute("class", "well");
    overview.setAttribute("style", "max-height: 300px;overflow: auto;");


    var list = document.createElement('ul');
    list.setAttribute("id", "check-list-box");
    list.setAttribute("class", "list-group checked-list-box");

    overview.appendChild(list);

    // Create the list element
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      // Create the list item
      var item = document.createElement('li');
      item.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item");
      item.setAttribute("id", "checkedData");

      // Set its contents
      item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

      // Add it to the list
      list.appendChild(item);

    }//end for loop

    var checkedItems = [], counter = 0;
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item"));
    
    var li = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item");
    console.log(li.length); 

    //loop through li elements in categories to add listeners
    for(var i = 0 ; i < li.length; i++){
      console.log("INSIDE");
      li[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //disallow repeats
        if(checkedItems.indexOf(li[i].innerText) == -1){
          checkedItems[counter] = li[i].innerText;
          counter++;
          console.log("added");
        }

        //remove element if unchecked from array
        if($('checkedData').is(':checked') == false){
          var index = checkedItems.indexOf(li[i].innerText);
          console.log(li[i].innerText +": " + index);
          checkedItems.splice(index, 1);
          console.log("disabled");
          counter--;
        }

      });

    }
      
    console.log("AFTER");
    // Finally, return the constructed list
    return list;
  }

  document.getElementById('cat').appendChild(makeUL(categories));
```

Comment: looks like you haven't appended your overview element to the dom

Comment: _`getElementsByClassName` returns live HTMLCollection of found elements._ By the time you access `.length` property, elements is not appended yet!

Comment: The linked dupetarget explains why you're seeing what you're seeing in the console. Note that `document.getElementsByClassName` will only find elements that are in the document. Your code above is creating elements, and then searching for them in the document, and only *later* adding them to the document.

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) is the solution to your **next** problem (using `i` inside the event handlers you're creating in a loop).

Comment: +1 Thanks to Rayon for "elements is not appended yet". Can't believe I missed that! And TJ for the follow up on `i` error immediately after fixing this error.